# Evaluation of the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor na \rfloor} \left \lfloor ia \right \rfloor $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Let $a$ be a positive proper fraction and $n$ is any integer then evaluate the following sum,
> $$\sum_{i=1}^{\left \lfloor na \right \rfloor\atop} \left \lfloor ia \right \rfloor $$

I think that probably some counting argument will give us a solution of the problem but I can't find it. Any help is appreciated.

Actually the question aroused due to my efforts in trying to find out a simple formula for calculating the Legendre Symbol. Following is my approach to finding a closed form for the sum $$\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \left \lfloor \dfrac{ia}{p} \right \rfloor $$ where $\operatorname{gcd}(a,p)=1$ and $a$ is odd.

> **My Try**
>
> I have tried to approach the above problem in the following manner. Consider a rectangle in the Cartesian Plane with coordinates of the vertices $A(0,0)$, $B(\dfrac{p}{2},0)$, $C(\dfrac{p}{2},\dfrac{a}{2})$ and $D(0,\dfrac{a}{2})$.
>
> Now draw the two diagonals $AC$ and $BD$. Let them intersect at $O$. Denote the number of lattice points in region $R$ with no lattice point (if any) on the boundaries is counted by $\Lambda(R)$.
>
> Then using this notation we have, $$\Lambda(\triangle AOB)+\Lambda(\triangle BOC)+\Lambda(\triangle COD)+\Lambda(\triangle DOA)=\Lambda(\square ABCD)$$
>
> But since $\triangle AOB \equiv \triangle COD$ and $\triangle BOC \equiv \triangle DOA$, we get $\Lambda(\triangle AOB)=\Lambda(\triangle COD)$ and $\Lambda(\triangle BOC)=\Lambda(\triangle DOA)$
>
> Therefor our expression reduces to, $$2(\Lambda(\triangle AOB)+\Lambda(\triangle BOC)=\Lambda(\square ABCD) \implies 2\Lambda(\triangle ABC)=\Lambda(\square ABCD)$$
>
> But, $$\Lambda(\triangle ABC)=\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \left \lfloor \dfrac{ia}{p} \right \rfloor $$ and $$\Lambda(\square ABCD)=\left(\dfrac{p-1}{2} \right)\left \lfloor \dfrac{a}{2} \right \rfloor$$ hence we have, $$2\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \left \lfloor \dfrac{ia}{p} \right \rfloor=\left(\dfrac{p-1}{2} \right)\left(\dfrac{a-1}{2} \right )$$

But from this I can't interpret the given sum. What is the mistake? There must be a mistake because the parity of both side of the inequality doesn't hold if $p \equiv a \equiv 3$ $(\operatorname{mod}4)$. Can anyone help me in this respect?

Answer (score 3):

Let $a = \displaystyle\frac{p}{q}$ where $(p,q) = 1$ and $p < q$. Then:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor na\rfloor} \lfloor ia \rfloor = \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor na\rfloor} ia - \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor na\rfloor} \lbrace ia \rbrace $$

Where $\lbrace x\rbrace$ is the fractional part of $x$.

Note that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor na\rfloor} \lbrace ia \rbrace = \frac{1}{q}\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor na\rfloor} ip\text{ mod }q $$

We can get some interesting results from that depending on $n \text{ mod }q$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you got to the second summation involving mod q.

Comment: @KBusc Using integer division we have $ip = cq + r$ where $0 \leq r < q$ (in fact, $r = ip \mod q$ and $c = \lfloor ia\rfloor$) so $\frac{ip}{q} = c + \frac{r}{q} = \lfloor ai\rfloor + \frac{ip\mod q}{q}$

Comment: Ahh thank you very much, that makes sense.

Comment: Can't there be obtained any closed form of the sum?

Comment: @user170039 that depends on the divisibility of $n$ by $q$ and on wether $q$ is prime or not.

Comment: Suppose that $q \nmid n$ and $q$ is a prime. Then?

Comment: Well, since $p$ and $q$ are coprime, then as $i$ goes from $1$ to $q$, $ip \text{ mod } q$ goes through every number from $0$ to $q-1$, so if $\lfloor na\rfloor = cq + r$ then you add all the values from $0$ to $q-1$ $c$ times (and some more values, corresponding to the $r$. All the values from $0$ to $q-1$ add up to $q(q-1)/2$ so:

$$\frac{1}{q}\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor na\rfloor} ip \text { mod } q = \frac{q-1}{2} + \frac{1}{q}\sum_{i=1}^r ip \text { mod } q$$

Comment: The primality of $q$ is not necessary, sorry. If $q | \lfloor na\rfloor$ then $r = 0$ so the last sum is $0$

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an answer but I couln't get this to look correct as comment. But I think $$ 0 <\sum_{i=1}^{\left \lfloor na \right \rfloor} \left \lfloor ia \right \rfloor < a\cdot {\left \lfloor na \right \rfloor}\frac{{\left \lfloor na \right \rfloor} + 1}{2} $$

Should be true.

Comment: Sorry for the terrible syntax but I am not sure how to do the fraction correctly

Comment: Try \frac{ numerator } { denominator } or just { numerator \over denominator }

Comment: You are missing a factor of $a$. Since $\lfloor ia \rfloor \leq ia$ we have $\sum \lfloor ia \rfloor  \leq a \cdot \frac{\lfloor na \rfloor(\lfloor na \rfloor + 1)}{2}$.